# Android Cloud app build fails every time

Tags: android, google-app-engine

I am new to Android App Engine. I created a sample app by following the instructions in [GitHub](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gradle-appengine-templates/tree/master/HelloWorld). When I tried to run the servlet backend, it is not compiling and is giving this message.

> Error:Gradle: A problem occurred configuring root project 'Cloudtest2'.
>   Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':classpath'.
>   Could not resolve com.android.tools:common:24.1.0.
>        Required by:
>            :Cloudtest2:unspecified > com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.1.0 > com.android.tools.build:gradle-core:1.1.0 > com.android.tools.build:builder:1.1.0
>            :Cloudtest2:unspecified > com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.1.0 > com.android.tools.build:gradle-core:1.1.0 > com.android.tools.build:builder:1.1.0 > com.android.tools.build:manifest-merger:24.1.0
>            :Cloudtest2:unspecified > com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.1.0 > com.android.tools.build:gradle-core:1.1.0 > com.android.tools.build:builder:1.1.0 > com.android.tools.ddms:ddmlib:24.1.0
>            :Cloudtest2:unspecified > com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.1.0 > com.android.tools.build:gradle-core:1.1.0 > com.android.tools.build:builder:1.1.0 > com.android.tools:sdklib:24.1.0 > com.android.tools.layoutlib:layoutlib-api:24.1.0
>            :Cloudtest2:unspecified > com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.1.0 > com.android.tools.build:gradle-core:1.1.0 > com.android.tools.build:builder:1.1.0 > com.android.tools:sdklib:24.1.0 > com.android.tools:dvlib:24.1.0
>   Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/common/24.1.0/common-24.1.0.pom'. Received status code 500 from server: Internal Server Error`

I've installed the cloud sdk, re-installed the app engine sdk and still not working. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I did the following : gradlew clean and then gradlew assemble. 
It gave me the real stack (a real error in my gradle file).
I hope it will help you.